# Convert KeplerGl html file to iframe

Tags: python, sharepoint, databricks, kepler.gl

I have created a map using KeplerGl in Databricks. I saved the file using:

```
map_1._repr_html_().decode("utf-8")
```

I opened the html file in a text editor to find the iframe information, but it didn't exist. I then tried some of the src links in the text editor, but those just brought up more lines of code. I'm trying to embed into a sharepoint site. Is there a way for me to embed my html map into sharepoint, and interact with it as you would with a google maps embed?

I don't know how useful the html code would be, but I can't post it because of the spam filter, and I don't know how to get around that.

I think keplergl 0.2.0 had a function that allowed you to embed, but I'm not sure how I could use that version.

I also thought about loading the html map into mapbox, and then getting my embed from there, but I have no idea how I'd even start to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keplergl module's built in function to save the html "this will save map with provided data and config". Then you can saved html, in here "first_map.html" inside a iframe in your web application. Hope this will works for you.

```
keplergl.save_to_html(data={"data_1": df}, config=config, file_name='first_map.html')
```